# Ajax PHP Article Paginator

Tags: php, ajax, paginator

I'm trying to find code to paginate a long post via Ajax and Php, e.g
My post has more than 2000 words, I would like to break the page into several pages with next& previous links with each page having 500 words. So in total 4 links should be displayed.

What I have gotten so far are plugins which paginate database records.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: In short -> ajax post to a php file, php file gets the split data (so you'd pass a limit/offset variable for your query) and return the results onto the page.. In the php page you'd create the structure for the prev/next/total pages buttons as you'll have all the information available

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check how many characters are there in an article you can use a PHP `strlen()` function. Then if it's greater than 500 you can set up a new link with `$_GET`... I don't know that you have a database but I recommend it to save the article in a mysql database.
**Code:**

```
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articles WHERE account_name=?"; // or you can use an strlen function here
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$u);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($rows);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
// Here we have the total row count
// This is the number of results we want displayed per page
$page_rows = 10;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1;
// Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
// This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$u.'&pn='.$previous.'#posts">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; '; // here we set up the link
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$u.'&pn='.$i.'#posts">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$u.'&pn='.$i.'#posts">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="user.php?u='.$u.'&pn='.$next.'#posts">Next</a> ';
    }
}
```

Since I don't know what do you want exactly watch this video: [pagination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14lGC4r1HKE&t=250s)

Comment: Hello Mark Frankli, Thanks alot for your response.                                         However as I had indicated, what you have given me is an Ajax paginator for database records. What I needed was an ajax paginator of an article e.g the way a Wordpress post has a next and previous button for a long blog post.

Comment: If you have only one article that is very long then you can simply use an automated function that loads the content everytime when you reach the bottom of the page. I would not recommend to split one article into more parts but if you really want to you can easily do it with the code above by deleting and rewriting the database interaction part.